# How to customize the highlighed text color in UISegmentedControl in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am working on the customization of UISegmentedControl in iOS5. I am using the new method `- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forState:(UIControlState)state`.

However, it seems that I can customize the text color in normal state. As I checked the documentation, the text attributes include only: `UITextAttributeFont`, `UITextAttributeTextColor`, `UITextAttributeTextShadowColor` and `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset`.

How can I specify the font color when a UISegmentedControl button is pressed (highlighted) ?

Comment: So if you do `[myControl setTitleTextAttributes:myAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];` doesn't it have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` of your [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) or generally use the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) protocol, introduced in iOS5. The concept stays the same.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                         UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor blueColor]
                         } forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```